# how to write store procedure from two table

Tags: sql

i have 2 tables table - `t1` and `t2`. From `t1` I want to select the columns `order_no` & `order_Id` In the table `t2` there are two columns - `order_no` and `inv_no`.

I want to select and display the `order_no` and `order_id` from table `t1`, and if the `order_no` has `inv_no` in table `t2`, I have to append that to the `order_no` like this => `ord1002_inv045`..

Comment: Your english is a little off track but If you would like to combine two tables to form 1 select script, there should be a reference or a foreign key to match the two tables. If you have that, then we can proceed with the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
SELECT OrderNo = t1.order_no
    , OrderId = t1.order_Id
    , OrderNoWithInvoiceId = 
      CASE 
        WHEN t2.inv_no IS NULL 
            THEN t1.order_no 
        ELSE t1.order_no + '_' + t2.inv_no 
      END 
FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.order_no = t2.order_no
```